# Assorting linked list in c

Tags: c, list, sorting, linked-list

i have a list of this struct and i want to sort the list depending on the value 
of draw_number, and the list has a pointer front that points to the first struct
of the list and a pointer rear that points on the last struct of the list .I found many codes for sorting a list but i can't do my job for my code. the struct is:

```
typedef struct itm{
    int draw_number;
    char date[11];
    char temi[6];
    struct itm *next;
}item;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest will be bubble sort.

```
item* sort(item *start){
    item *node1,*node2;
    int temp;
    for(node1 = start; node1!=NULL;node1=node1->next){
        for(node2 = start; node2!=NULL;node2=node2->next){
            if(node2->draw_number > node1->draw_number){
                temp = node1->draw_number;
                node1->draw_number = node2->draw_number;
                node2->draw_number = temp;
            }
        }
    }
return start;
}
```

Comment: thank you !!! bubble sort is much more easier! to understand